# Hadith: You would be able to hear what I hear

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> **If you do not allow your heart to be rolled in all directions and not practice excess speech, and not practice excess in speech, you would be able to hear what I
>   hear.**

(My guess is that the above is a somewhat rough translation.) What is the source (if it exists) of the above hadith?

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦ I am aware of your reference, but then the above translation would be too much of a paraphrasing. (And unnecessarily.)

Answer (score 1):

The hadith statement:
 <sub>In the following I'm translating from Arabic as these are my own translations take them with the necessary.</sub>

> ولولا تمرغ قلوبكم وتزيدكم في الحديث لسمعتم ما أسمع
> If there was not the wallow of your heart and your exaggeration in speech you may hear what I hear.

appears in a longer hadith compiled at-Targheeb (at-Targhyb) wa at-Tarheeb (at-Tarhyb) الترغيب والترهيب of imam al-Mundhiri [المنذري](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B0%D8%B1%D9%8A) where he say that it was compiled by imam Ahmad and ibn Majah on the authority of abu Umamah(), here I'll only translate the comment of imam al-Mundhiri on the hadith -the statement of your quote is marked in bold letters-:

> 261 - وعن أمامة رضي الله عنه قال مر النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم في يوم شديد الحر نحو بقيع الغرقد
> قال وكان الناس يمشون خلفه قال فلما سمع صوت النعال وقر ذلك في نفسه فجلس حتى قدمهم أمامه فلما مر ببقيع الغرقد إذا بقبرين قد دفنوا فيهما رجلين
> قال فوقف النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم فقال من دفنتم هاهنا اليوم
> قالوا فلان وفلان
> قالوا يا نبي الله وما ذاك قال أما أحدهما فكان لا يتنزه من البول وأما الآخر فكان يمشي بالنميمة وأخذ جريدة رطبة فشقها ثم جعلها على القبرين قالوا يا نبي الله لم فعلت هذا قال ليخففن عنهما
> قالوا يا رسول الله حتى متى هما يعذبان قال غيب لا يعلمه إلا الله **ولولا تمرغ قلوبكم وتزيدكم في الحديث لسمعتم ما أسمع**
> رواه أحمد واللفظ له وابن ماجه كلاهما من طريق علي بن يزيد الالهاني عن القاسم عنه  (Source [Islamport](http://islamport.com/d/1/akh/1/36/277.html))
> This hadith was compiled by imam Ahmad and this wording is his and ibn Majah both via 'Ali ibn Yazid al-Alhany from al-Qassim   الْقَاسِمَ أَبَا عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ from him (abu Umamah)

'Ali ibn Yazid al-Alhany علي بن يزيد الالهاني  is considered as rejected (munkar al Hadith). The person whom narrated it from him in both Sunan ibn Majah and Musnad Ahmad: Mu'an ibn Rif'ah as-Sulami معان بن رفاعة is considered as da'if. Therefore it appears also in al-Albani's book da'if at-Targheeb wa at-Tarheeb as it is da'if. Al-Mundhiri has quoted this hadith three times this was the first then he quoted it as a hadith of imam Ahmad and as a narration of Ahmad and at-Tabari (which can be found [here](http://www.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=339&hid=14&pid=70268) -in Arabic- in at-Tabari's Sarih as-Sunnah the narrators of this chain are mostly trustworthy and it expresses a doubt that one of the two buried people might a woman, this version has some more deviation) all three narrations appear in al-Albani's book so he considered all of them as da'if.

I only found the first part of the hadith mentioned by ibn Majah with a deviation that I've put in bold letters, but this also appears [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=121&pid=62065&hid=21704) in Musnad Ahmad, so maybe either al-Mundhiri or somebody else left it out:

> It was narrated that Abu Umamah said:
> "The Prophet walked on a very hot day towards Baqi' Al-Gharqad (graveyard of Al-Madinah), and the people were walking behind him. When he heard the sound of their shoes, it affected his soul so he sat down until he made them go ahead of him, **lest that make him feel too proud**."

Maybe you are interested how the hadith goes forth here an other translation of mine of the addition in Musnad Ahmad -the part coverd in ibn Majah's Sunan is put in bold letters-:

> **عَنْ  أَبِي أُمَامَةَ  , قَالَ : مَرَّ النَّبِيُّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ فِي يَوْمٍ شَدِيدِ الْحَرِّ نَحْوَ بَقِيعِ الْغَرْقَدِ , قَالَ : فَكَانَ النَّاسُ يَمْشُونَ خَلْفَهُ , قَالَ : فَلَمَّا سَمِعَ صَوْتَ النِّعَالِ , وَقَرَ ذَلِكَ فِي نَفْسِهِ , فَجَلَسَ حَتَّى قَدَّمَهُمْ أَمَامَهُ لِئَلَّا يَقَعَ فِي نَفْسِهِ شَيْءٌ مِنَ الْكِبْرِ** ,
> فَلَمَّا مَرَّ بِبَقِيعِ الْغَرْقَدِ , إِذَا بِقَبْرَيْنِ قَدْ دَفَنُوا فِيهِمَا رَجُلَيْنِ ,
> so when he reached the Bai' Al-Gharqad, they have buried two men,
>
> قَالَ : فَوَقَفَ النَّبِيُّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ فَقَالَ :  " مَنْ دَفَنْتُمْ هَاهُنَا الْيَوْمَ ؟ " ,
> He said (abu Umamah): the prophet Allahs prayers and blessings be upon him stopped and asked them: "Who have you buried here today?"
>
> قَالُوا : يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ , فُلَانٌ وَفُلَانٌ , قَالَ : " إِنَّهُمَا لَيُعَذَّبَانِ الْآنَ , وَيُفْتَنَانِ فِي قَبْرَيْهِمَا " ,
> They answered: Oh prophet of Allah, so-andso, He said: "They are punished now (at the moment) and tried in their graves".
>
> قَالُوا : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ , فِيمَ ذَاكَ ؟ قَالَ : " أَمَّا أَحَدُهُمَا فَكَانَ لَا يَتَنَزَّهُ مِنَ الْبَوْلِ , وَأَمَّا الْآخَرُ
> فَكَانَ يَمْشِي بِالنَّمِيمَةِ "
> They asked: "Oh Messneger of Allah, for what?"
> He answered: "One of them used not to take care to avoid getting urine on his body or clothes, and the other used to walk about spreading gossip."
>
> وَأَخَذَ جَرِيدَةً رَطْبَةً فَشَقَّهَا , ثُمَّ جَعَلَهَا عَلَى الْقَبْرَيْنِ , قَالُوا : يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ , وَلِمَ فَعَلْتَ ؟ قَالَ : " لِيُخَفَّفَ عَنْهُمَا "
> Then he took a fresh palm stalk and broke it in half, and planted one half on each grave. They said: 'O Messenger of Allah, why did not do that?' He said: 'To reduced it for them."'
>
> , قَالُوا : يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ , وَحَتَّى مَتَى يُعَذِّبُهُمَا اللَّهُ ؟ قَالَ : " غَيْبٌ لَا يَعْلَمُهُ إِلَّا اللَّهُ " , قَالَ : " وَلَوْلَا تَمَزُّعُ قُلُوبِكُمْ أَوْ تَزَيُّدُكُمْ فِي الْحَدِيثِ , لَسَمِعْتُمْ مَا أَسْمَعُ "  .
> They further asked: Oh prophet of Allah and until when will Allah punish them?
> He answered: "The unseen (ghayb) of Allah is only known by HIM". He said: "If there was not the wallow of your heart and your exaggeration in speech you may hear what I hear."

Note that the part telling about the punishment of these two people is mentioned in the sahih sunnah too (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1361), [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/143) and [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai:2069)) , so the hadith is basically classified as da'if for Its additions.